# css3 animation delay on right side only

Tags: html, css

I am creating CSS3 animation to make a `div` move infinity from left to right.

The code is working except for when the `div` goes to right side, it has a delay of 3 seconds. On the left side, it is working great.

Here is my code:

```css
#najava {
  width: 197px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0.8;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  animation: mymove 5s linear 0s infinite alternate-reverse;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 200px;
  }
}
@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    background-color: transparent;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
  }
  33% {
    background-color: yellow;
    left: 250px;
    right: 0px;
  }
  66% {
    background-color: blue;
    left: 250px;
    right: 250px;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: green;
    left: 0px;
    right: 250px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="najava">
  <p>text text text text text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different organization of keyframes, maybe?

```css
#najava { 
    width: 197px;
    height: 22px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: transparent;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    animation: mymove 3s linear 0s infinite alternate-reverse;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;

}


@keyframes mymove {
   0% { left: 0px; }
    100% { left: 200px; }
  }
@keyframes mymove {
   0%   {background-color:transparent; left:0px; }
    25%  {background-color:yellow; left:100px; }
    50%  {background-color:blue; left:200px; }
    75%  {background-color:red; left:100px; }
    100%  {background-color:green; left:0px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="najava">
  <p>text text text text text</p>
 </div>
```

p.s. added 5 steps but you can play with the values...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **reason** why this is happening.

Your problem lies in the fact that at *66%*, nothing is happening. The `left` remains at `250px` which makes it just stay where it's at. The animation is running as it is programmed to do.

To fix this unwanted behavior, you need to remove the *66%* line and change it to a simple 0%, 50%, 100% animation.

```
@keyframes mymove {
    0%   {background-color:transparent; left:0px; right:0px;}
    50%  {background-color:yellow; left:250px; right:0px;}
    100%  {background-color:green; left:0px; right:250px;}
}
```

This alteration ensures that at 50%, the div is to the right, and at 100%/0%, it's all the way to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Change your css a bit

**CSS**:

```
@keyframes mymove {
  0%   {background-color:transparent; left:0px}
  33%  {background-color:yellow; left:250px}
  66%  {background-color:blue; left:0px; right:250px;}
  100%  {background-color:green; left:250px;}
}
```

**Full working code:**

```css
#najava { 
    width: 197px;
    height: 22px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: transparent;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    animation: mymove 5s linear 0s infinite alternate-reverse;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

@keyframes mymove {
    0%   {background-color:transparent; left:0px}
    33%  {background-color:yellow; left:250px}
    66%  {background-color:blue; left:0px; right:250px;}
    100%  {background-color:green; left:250px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="najava">
  <p>text text text text text</p>
</div>
```

Here is the working **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/r7bkhyoa/)**